# Should I answer the question if someone has already answered it in a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, duplicate-answers

I came across a question:

[How to remove specefic rows from linq result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720500/how-to-remove-specefic-rows-from-linq-result)

I see that there is already a comment that has answered the question and OP has already "accepted" it with another comment. Should I provide a more detailed answer?

I think I should. Because adding the answer does not count as a duplicate answer because the other "answer" is a comment. So there isn't technically a duplicate. Am I right?

Comment: Quote: "I realise that it was silly question".  Silly questions should be deleted by the OP.  As long as they don't, nobody is going to stop you from answering them.  Whether your free time is invested well, hmya, odds are never that good.